# Getting the below warning while trying to retrieve records from CassandraDB from Python code

Tags: cassandra

While running the Python script to retrieve records from Cassandra DB getting warning messages like " Last error: No route to host" and time taking more than 1 minute for 70k records

In Cassandra DB the select query result gives in 3 seconds. But the python scripts taking more than 1 min 50 sec and gives warning like

```
 OSError: [Errno 113] Tried connecting to [('10.184.20.196', 9042)]. Last error: No route to host
WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Host 10.184.20.196 has been marked down
WARNING:cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 10.114.20.126, scheduling retry in 2.0 seconds: [Errno 113] Tried connecting to [('10.114.20.126', 9042)]. Last error: No route to host

WARNING:cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 10.114.20.126, scheduling retry in 4.0 seconds: [Errno 113] Tried connecting to [('10.114.20.126', 9042)]. Last error: No route to host

WARNING:cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 
10.114.20.126, scheduling retry in 16.0 seconds: [Errno 113] Tried connecting to [('10.114.20.126', 9042)]. Last error: No route to host

INFO:werkzeug:169.144.102.112 - - [27/Aug/2019 22:10:05] "GET /fso/sitedb?circle=MP&lat=25.4248&long=77.6555&rad=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

WARNING:cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 10.114.20.126, scheduling retry in 64.0 seconds: [Errno 113] Tried connecting to [('10.114.20.126', 9042)]. Last error: No route to host
```

Comment: No route to host typically occurs while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

Comment: check if you can telnet the host and port 9042 from the server where python code is being run